# Python: keyboard input and continue?

Tags: python, loops, debugging

I want to run this python script over and over in notepad. But Have issues when running the program - it only prints once then it stops. How can make this program run until I stop it manually?

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller ()

time.sleep(2)

for char in "print this is notepad over and over":
    keyboard.press(char)
    keyboard.release(char)
    time.sleep(0.12)
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another loop if you want your program to run over and over. Try this (you can improve the stop condition if you want)

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller 
import time 
keyboard = Controller ()
time.sleep(2) 
while True:
    for char in "print this is notepad over and over": 
        keyboard.press(char) 
        keyboard.release(char) 
        time.sleep(0.12) 
        continue
```